Colouring different datasets Algebra of Graphics (Julia)
I am using Algebra of Graphics to plot multiple datasets in the following way:
function filterPlot(filterPos)
    
    #filterPos - a vector of vectors 


     dataForPlot = data(DataFrame(xx = 1:length(filterPos[1]), yy = filterPos[1]))
        for thing in filterPos[2:end]
            plotFilter = DataFrame(xx = 1:length(thing), yy = thing)
            dataForPlot =dataForPlot + data(plotFilter)
        end

        
   
    
    dataForPlot *= mapping(:1=>(t->t) ,:2 => (t->t)); # data(toBePlotted)*mapping(:a =>(t->t) =>"Time (d)",:b => (t->t)=>"Weight")*linear();

    plaxis = (xlabel = xlab, ylabel = ylab)

    drawing = draw(dataForPlot;axis = plaxis,palettes=(; color=ColorSchemes.Set1_3.colors))
end

Note that filterPos can have arbitrary many data sets in it. Ideally I would like each one of them displayed in a separate colour (one that I do not need to set manually).
I know matplotlib automatically colours things. Is there something like that in Makie or AlgebraofGraphics?

It looks like you are combining data by generating a bunch of individual DataFrame objects from each of the vectors passed to filterPlot, then summing them by effectively doing AlgebraOfGraphics.data(df1) + AlgebraOfGraphics.data(df2) + .... That works, but if you just want each of those DataFrames to have a different hue in your plot while applying the same mapping and visual to all of them, consider combining the DataFrames first along with a dummy variable that identifies the vector of origin.
To do that, start by combining the vector of vectors into a long DataFrame:
using DataFrames, CairoMakie, AlgebraOfGraphics

# fake data: 5 vectors of random size containing lines of data with noise
rand_line(slope, n) = slope .* (1:n) .+ randn(n)
filterPos = [rand_line(slope, rand(10:20)) for slope in 1:5]

# a function to convert a Vector to a DataFrame in the format you want
vec_to_df((id, values)) = DataFrame(label = id, xx = 1:length(values), yy = values)

# combine all the vectors by mapping our vec_to_df function to each and reducing with vcat
df = mapreduce(vec_to_df, vcat, enumerate(filterPos))

At this point, you can follow the example from the AlgebraOfGraphics documentation for the linear function:
# plot, using the :label column as non-numeric to separate datasets
draw(data(df) * mapping(:xx, :yy, color = :label => nonnumeric) * (linear() + visual(Scatter)))

Result:


As a side note. In the plot above, do you know what colour scheme Algebra of Graphics is using?

AlgebraOfGraphics uses Makie to draw graphics, and Makie's default categorical colormap is from Wong 2011. All the available pre-made colormaps are listed at https://docs.makie.org/stable/explanations/colors#Colormaps.
